# Laravel Carbon formatting error

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I'm experiencing a weird problem.

I'm using Carbon for dates. I want to use the format Y-W (year,week) which is working correctly.
Here i store it into the DB:

```
$weekDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-y', "{$key}")->format('Y-W');

DB::table('backorder_voorspelling')->insert([
    'artikelcode' => $articlecode,
    'week' => $weekDate,
    'aantal' => $value,
    'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
    'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
]);
```

The database record is correct:

```
{#426 ▼
  +"id": 1
  +"artikelcode": "articlecode"
  +"week": "2017-44"
  +"aantal": "6"
  +"created_at": "2018-01-18 11:46:45"
  +"updated_at": "2018-01-18 11:46:45"
}
```

Later on i want to convert the Y-W back to a carbon time and this is telling me:

[image]

The code i use to create the carbon time:

```
$startOfWeek = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-W', $row->week);
```

The formats are the same, when storing i use the format ('Y-W') and when creatingFromFormat i use the format ('Y-W'), yet it's not working...

I tried replacing the - for / but this returns the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all date format characters can be used in `DateTime::createFromFormat` (which is what Carbon extends). Unfortunately for you, `W` is one of the ones that's missing.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

> The format that the passed in string should be in. See the formatting options below. In **most** cases, the same letters as for the date() can be used.

You can work round this by manually calling `setISODate` on a new DateTime (or Carbon) instance:

```
list ($year, $week) = explode('-', '2017-44');
$d = new DateTime;
$d->setISODate($year, $week);
```

`setISODate` also accepts a third `$day` parameter - by default it will set to the first day of the week, which I think is what you want.

See https://eval.in/937360